# Redshift Pause and Resume

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

With Redshift's Pause and Resume feature, do we pay for both the storage used on the cluster and for the snapshots? If yes to the storage on the cluster, then how do we calculate the storage cost because today we pay combined for both the computing and the storage?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

From [Overview of managing clusters in Amazon Redshift - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/managing-cluster-operations.html#rs-mgmt-pause-resume-cluster):

> When you pause a cluster, Amazon Redshift creates a snapshot
>   ...
>   When you pause a cluster, billing is suspended.

From [Amazon Redshift Pricing - Cloud Data Warehouse - Amazon Web Services](https://aws.amazon.com/redshift/pricing/):

> The pause and resume feature allows you to suspend on-demand billing during the time the cluster is paused. During the time that a cluster is paused **you only pay for backup storage**.

Therefore, it seems that **you would only be charged for the snapshot**.